# Login problem - extract and store information from query

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and need help. I have login form and I am sending username and password using POST method. How to extract data on my .php page and remember that user is logged in ( my username and password are hardcodded in code ) ? Do I need to store this on hd ( it is on embedded plc so I cannot use HD to store information )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting post data is easy: `<?php echo $_POST['fieldname']; ?>`

Remembering the logged-in user is a bit trickier.
You have to call `session_start()` at the beginning of your script, so you can store the user-related stuff in between web requests like this: `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`. You don't have to store the data on hard disk, PHP provides a function for you to set callbacks to handle session saving and restoring.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php